# Using PubNub History Android API

Tags: android, json, pubnub

I have worked with `pubnub.history(channel, true, 100, new Callback() { ...}` method and successfully received my last 100 conversation history. The response is given below:

```
[[{"message":"hdjcjcjjckckckckvkckckck","timetoken":14151866297757284},{"message":"nexusS","timetoken":14152599862541295},{"message":"nexusS","timetoken":14152600307899119},{"message":"Qmobile","timetoken":14152600563127702},{"message":"qMobile","timetoken":14152600865145050},{"message":"NexusS","timetoken":14152601034959154},{"message":"qMobile","timetoken":14152601234812083}],14151866297757284,14152601234812083]
```

But the problem is that how could i know that which message belongs to whom like if Person A send : nexusS  and Person B send: Qmobile  then how could i know through this message. Like there is no ID or identity number in which i could know that the conversation messages belongs to that particular person. I am working on application in which i want to display the conversation of both users seperately like skype conversation in which we can easily determine with our TAG name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to just add a senderID inside the message JSON itself. For example:

```
{"senderID":"usman", "data":{"color":"red","size":"medium","section":4}}
```

Then you could parse on senderID.  Another way to it is to segregate by channel name too. So you already know everything in channelUsman-iOS is from Usman on iOS.

geremy

Comment: thanks for your kind reply. It is working now, i have made Json message which contains String, IMEI. When it is land on Pubnub i can easily recognize users according to imei comparison. I am opening another new thread question regarding to History.